# PHP не подключается файл Requre_once

Tags: php

Здраствуйте!
Проблема в следующем есть сайт я его разделил на блоки Head, content, sidebar и footer в index.php require работает и подлкючает файл с базой данных и сами блоки но когда я ссылаюсь на файл коннекта с базой данных из под head.php (Из под блока) файл не подключается не могу понять почему пути прописаны правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения понял что нужно было указывать файл относительно index.php а не от блока.

Comment: Еще есть константа `__DIR__` http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php